# Ember: how to set classNameBindings on parent element of view

Tags: ember.js

See http://jsfiddle.net/4ZyBM/6/

I want to use Bootstrap for my UI elements and I am now trying to convert certain elements to Ember views.  I have the following problem:

I embed an input element in a DIV with a given class (control-group).  If a validation error occurs on the field, then I want to add an extra class "error" to the DIV.

I can create a view based on the Ember.TextField and specify that if the error occurs the ClassNameBinding should be "error", but the problem is that class is the set to the input element and not to the DIV.

You can test this by entering a non alpha numeric character in the field. I would like to see the DIV border in red and not the input field border.

HTML:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div class="control-group">
    {{view App.AlphaNumField valueBinding="value" type="text" classNames="inputField"}}
    </div>
</script>
```

JS:

```
App.AlphaNumField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  isValid: function () {
    return /^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(this.get('value'));
  }.property('value'),
  classNameBindings: 'isValid::error'
})
```

Can I set the classNameBindings on the parent element or the element closest to the input ?  In jQUery I would use:

```
$(element).closest('.control-group').addClass('error');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing here is that without using jQuery you cannot access easily the wrapping div around you `Ember.TextField`'s. Also worth mentioning is that there might be also a hundred ways of doing this, but the simplest solution I can think of would be to create a simple `Ember.View` as a wrapper and check the underlying child views for validity.

#### Template

```
{{#view App.ControlGroupView}}
  {{view App.AlphaNumField 
    valueBinding="value" 
    type="text" 
    classNames="inputField" 
    placeholder="Alpha num value"}}
{{/view}}
```

#### Javascript

```
App.ControlGroupView = Ember.View.extend({
  classNameBindings: 'isValid:control-group:control-group-error',
  isValid: function () {
    var validFields = this.get('childViews').filterProperty('isValid', true);
    var valid = validFields.get('length');
    var total = this.get('childViews').get('length')
    return (valid === total);
  }.property('childViews.@each.isValid')
});

App.AlphaNumField = Ember.TextField.extend({
  isValid: function () {
    return /^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(this.get('value'));
  }.property('value')
});
```

#### CSS

```
.control-group-error {
  border:1px solid red;
  padding:5px;
}

.control-group {
  border:1px solid green;
  padding:5px;
}
```

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4ZyBM/9/).

Regarding bootstrap-ember integration and for the sake of DRY your could also checkout this ember-addon: https://github.com/emberjs-addons/ember-bootstrap

Hope it helps.

Comment: Good to know that ember boostrap have this in the forms. In my epoch that does not exist. And I have reimplemented the wheel again :(

Comment: @intuitivepixel Seems to be a good approach and I will need to test this out.  Looks like the "working demo" link is not correct ...  refers to my initial question.  When I enter your solution, I receive a "nested views" error ...  Can you post a link to the correct working demo ?  Thx.  I will also have a look at ember-bootstrap.  Thx.

Comment: @cyclomarc, oh crap, sorry, wasn't logged in into jsfiddle, updated my answer with a new link, have a look

Comment: Perfect now.  Indeed works well and still understandable. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is the more **flexible** way to do this:

Javascript

```
Boostrap = Ember.Namespace.create();
```

To simplify the things each `FormControl` have the properties: label, message and an intern control. So you can extend it and specify what control you want. Like combobox, radio button etc.

```
Boostrap.FormControl = Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ['form-group'],
    classNameBindings: ['hasError'],    
    template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('\
      <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">{{view.label}}</label>\
      <div class="col-lg-10">\
        {{view view.control}}\
        <span class="help-block">{{view.message}}</span>\
      </div>'),
    control: Ember.required()
});
```

The `Boostrap.TextField` is one of the implementations, and your component is a `Ember.TextField`. Because that `Boostrap.TextField` is an instance of `Ember.View` and not an `Ember.TextField` directly. We delegate the value using `Ember.computed.alias`, so you can use `valueBinding` in the templates.

```
Boostrap.TextField = Boostrap.FormControl.extend({      
    control: Ember.TextField.extend({
        classNames: ['form-control'],
        value: Ember.computed.alias('parentView.value')
    })
});
```

Nothing special here, just create the defaults values tagName=form and classNames=form-horizontal, for not remember every time.

```
Boostrap.Form = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName: 'form',
    classNames: ['form-horizontal']    
});
```

Create a subclass of  `Boostrap.Form` and delegate the validation to controller, since it have to be the knowledge about validation.

```
App.LoginFormView = Boostrap.Form.extend({
    submit: function() {
        debugger;
        if (this.get('controller').validate()) {
            alert('ok');
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Here is where the validation logic and handling is performed. All using bindings without the need of touch the dom.

```
App.IndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    value: null,
    message: null,
    hasError: Ember.computed.bool('message'),
    validate: function() {
        this.set('message', '');
        var valid = true;
        if (!/^[a-z0-9]+$/i.test(this.get('value'))) {
            this.set('message', 'Just numbers or alphabetic letters are allowed');
            valid = false;
        }
        return valid;
    }
});
```

Templates

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{#view App.LoginFormView}}            
        {{view Boostrap.TextField valueBinding="value" 
                                label="Alpha numeric" 
                                messageBinding="message"
                                hasErrorBinding="hasError"}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
    {{/view}}
</script>
```

[Here a live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/marciojunior/e9fhB/)

## Update

Like @intuitivepixel have said, ember-boostrap have this implemented. So consider my sample if you don't want to have a dependency in ember-boostrap.

Comment: Gives me a very good insight in how a generic solution could be build. I now also start to understand the code in ember-bootstrap. Looks like your code and ember-bootstrap requires Bootstrap 3.0 (e.g. form-group and no longer control-group, etc.).